# Variance of a linear trasnformation of two normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$

Let $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$

$\text{COV}(X,Y) = -1$

Let  $T=Y-aX$ ( $a \neq 0$)

Find $a$ that makes $V(T)= 1$

So I found that $V(T)=2+2a^2+2a$

There's no solution for $V(T)= 1$

Comment: Check your algebra: there's a sign error, there's a missing factor of $a,$ and it's also possible the values of "$2$" are intended to be standard deviations rather than variances.

Comment: sorry it was a mistake
no I am positive that they are variances

Comment: You're right, there is no real root. The root is $-\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{3}$

Comment: You still have a sign error.

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry--I thought I had deleted that comment, because just after writing it I had come to the same conclusion.